# I am trying to do a cooldown but it doesn't working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to do a cooldown with talkedRecently, but it doesn't working, please help me.

```
const talkedRecently = new Set();
module.exports = {
    name: 'c',
    description: 'c!',
    execute(message, args) {
        if (talkedRecently.has(message.member.id)) {
            message.channel.send("You should wait 1 minute before use this command again")
        } else if(!talkedRecently.has(message.member.id)){
            message.channel.send("Your id sucsesfully added to talkedRecently")
            talkedRecently.add(message.member.id)
            setTimeout(() => {talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id), 60000})
            console.log(talkedRecently)
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to make a new set

```
var cooldown = new Set()
```

in Your message event Make bot check if the user in cooldown

```js
if(cooldown.has(msg.author.id)) return msg.reply("You're in cooldown")
```

if the user not in cooldown add him to cooldown and reply to him

```js
cooldown.add(message.author.id)
```

we need after given time remove him from cooldown, use setTimeout

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   cooldown.delete(message.author.id)
},3500)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `setTimeout` syntax is wrong.
This should be the syntax.

```
setTimeout(() => { talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id); }, 60000);
```